# Threads hang on selecting a channel

Tags: java, weblogic, solaris, nio

I am performance testing an application in WebLogic and at some point the performance starts degrading and I see all the threads that are serving http requests are stuck in this code

```
          sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.poll0(Native Method)

          sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.poll(DevPollArrayWrapper.java:223)

          sun.nio.ch.DevPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(DevPollSelectorImpl.java:84)

          sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)

          sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)

              weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.writeInternal(NIOSocketMuxer.java:1090)

              weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.write(NIOSocketMuxer.java:983)

          weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.writeToNetwork(JSSEFilterImpl.java:773)

          weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.wrapAndWrite(JSSEFilterImpl.java:734)
```

I believe the above means WebLogic does not have enough channel to send the responses back but I am not sure what setting is related to that. I have checked the file limit on the OS and it is set to unlimited. I am not sure what else I need to check. Any ideas? The code is running on a Solaris box running SunOS.

EDIT: Thread pool has been configured to initialize with minimum of 250 threads and can grow to 400 threads. At the point of the problem we are at 250 threads and only 60 of them are serving requests.

Comment: Post some relevant code, how you are configuring thread pool and all.

Comment: You are seeing a web server serving web traffic to the network.  What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's the top of the stack trace. Do you think that means it is doing the actual transmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Threads hang on selecting a channel

No.

> I believe the above means WebLogic does not have enough channel to send the responses back

No.

It is *one* thread *blocking* while *selecting on a network event,* and it means there is no incoming data, no space in the socket send buffers, etc., depending on what events are being selected on.

In this case is it being invoked by a write further down the stack, which indicates lack of space in the socket send buffer, which indicates that the peer is slow reading.

There's nothing you can do about that at this end.